# not able to get the Dismissing alert in express application

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am not getting the Dismissing Alert as shown in bootstrap when I Include it in Express application I am new to node.js and express so please help me

below an image is attached which is my file structure :

[file structure image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93yaI.png)

below is an image of my boilerplate code :

[boilerplate of my application click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe4uZ.png)

below is my file in which I have included my bootstrap Dismissing alert :
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp82j.png)

below is my output of Dismissing Alert :

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giVh6.png)

ignore the Dismissing alert message as I have kept that message temporarily

as you can see I am not getting the button to close the alert please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your `data-bs-dismiss` attribute on your close button markup, why do you have a "-bs-" in there? As far as I remember it's just `data-dismiss="alert"` (if you don't do it manually with jQuery `$('.alert').alert()`?

Comment: It was present in the bootstrap docs
I was using the latest version of bootstrap